# Can flask_login still work if Flask is being used at server side (backend) only?

Tags: python, flask, flask-login

I am working on a web app where Flask is used as backend and react as frontend. I was wondering if flask's flask-login extension which handle login and logout of users, can be used in this scenario. Flask is purely used at server side and deals with only API requests and sends response to frontend. Can flask-login handle user authentication and management (login/logout) in such case?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Flask login works with session, so it cannot be used in your case as the server will be stateless. you need to implement a jwt to be sent form you front-end (react) and handle it in your route.

You can use packages other than flask-login to do that such as flask-praetorian
easy to use here is the [link](https://pypi.org/project/flask-praetorian/)

```
guard = flask_praetorian.Praetorian()

app = flask.Flask(__name__)

guard.init_app(app, User) <-- User is your user model

@app.route("/protected")
@flask_praetorian.auth_required
def protected():
    ...
```

There are ofcourse other packages out there, but this one is kind of similar to flask-login